# Как записать транскрипцию слов

Tags: фонетика

Как записать транскрипцию слов
АГА. ОГО, УГУ, ГМ, ГОСПОДИ, С БОГОМ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

АГА. ОГО, УГУ, ГМ, ГОСПОДИ, С БОГОМ - во всех этих словах произносится  ɣ - знак обозначает редкий в русском языке звонкий задненебный фрикативный согласный, который может произноситься в некоторых словах (господи, бога, ага, бухгалтер), а также получается в результате озвончения [х] перед последующим звонким шумным согласным (их бы).

с богом - [збоɣъм], гм-ɣм, господи - [ɣоспъд'и]

Но сейчас допускается произношение господи и бог и через "г" - как вариант.